# Display data received from drop box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I would like once the user selects a different item in the drop box list which was taken from a mysql database, that specific data to that field be displayed.

Currently, I am able to get the value of the item in the drop down box but I am unable to use it.

```
<h3>Drop down Menu</h3>
<select id="dmenu">
  <option selected="selected" id="opt">Choose your station</option>
</select>
<div id="optionT"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  window.onload = ajaxCallback;

  function ajaxCallback(data) {
    var data;
    var myOptions;
    var output;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        //$.each(data, function (index, value) {

        var output = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

          output.push('<option value="' + key + '">' + value.Station +
            '</option>');
        });

        $('#dmenu').html(output.join(''));
      }
    })
  }
});

$('#dmenu').on('change', function() {

      //alert( this.value );
      //alert($(this).find(":selected").value());

      function stationData(data) {

        var stationName = $(this);
        alert(stationName.val());
        //var stationName = $(this).value();

        //var stationName = $(this).find(":selected").value()

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              station: stationName
            },

            success: (data) => {
              $.each(data, function(i) {


                  data[i]
                  //console.log(i);

                  var station_loopOp = '';

                  //console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i].Station));

                  station_loopOp += '<li>ID: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].ID) +
                    '</li>' +
                    '<li>Station: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Station) +
                    '</li>' + '<li>Address: 
                  '+JSON.stringify(data[i].Address)  +
                  '</li>' + '<li>' +
                  Sales: JSON.stringify(data[i].Monthly_CStore_Sales) +
                    '</li>' + '<li>Operator: ' +
                    JSON.stringify(data[i].Operator) + '</li>' +
                    '<li>Top SKU: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Top_SKU) +
                    '</li>' +
                    '</<li>' + '<br/>');

                $('#optionT').html(station_loopOp);
              }
            });
        }

      });
```

Comment: I think you should uncomment the `//var stationName = $(this).find(":selected").value()` as you are using it in AJAX as `data: {
              station: stationName
            },`

Comment: @Mukul Kumar Jha....Thank you but how can I use the value to display information about the station everytime a user changes the drop down......

Comment: Try putting your `change` listener on `#dmenu` inside the `$(document).ready(() => { /* Here*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

You are just defining the `function stationData(data){....}` inside the callback function but not calling it anywhere inside of it .

Add this line into your function : `stationData(<your-data>);`

Comment: @ Mukul kumar Jha.....so I'm headed in the right direction.....is the ajax post code method in the change function good? Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes your ajax request looks fine ... however it is good practice to use a bunch of `console.log` for debugging and to get a better understanding of the problem. See if it works for you.

Comment: Kumar Jha, I am getting an error in my ajax request on the change method....Should I be using the backend url: url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
        method: 'GET',.... as I did when receiving the data....or should I use a different url. I ask this because when I console log(data) in the change method function, I am getting the entire object instead of the value of the drop down box changed by the user....

Comment: Please post the updated code to help you better . However I suspect that there is a problem in assigning the value ...in the `$(this)`